# Differences between AtTask Sandbox and AtTask On-Demand

Tags: api, rest, attask

I've asked AtTask support and haven't gotten a reply in a couple weeks.
There appears to be a difference between AtTask Sandbox and AtTask On-Demand.  I have a script (PHP) developed to extract time-off from a SharePoint list and update the Time-Off calendar in AtTask.  It works perfectly in the Sandbox, but not at all in On-Demand.

Our Sandbox refreshes from production every weekend.  The users are identical and have identical permissions.  However, when I point my script at On-Demand, I can't even get the thing to log in.  Consequently, the rest of the process fails.

The URL I'm using to login to Sandbox - which works is:

"https://COMPANY.attasksandbox.com/attask/api/v4.0/login?username=USERNAME@COMPANY.COM&password=PASSWORD"

The URL which I'm using for On-Demand, which doesn't work is:

"https://COMPANY.attask-ondemand.com/attask/api/v4.0/login?username=USERNAME@COMPANY.COM&password=PASSWORD"

The login credentials work on both sites when entered from the login form, and provide the same exact user rights.  I've tested multiple sets of credentials with the same results.

One other thing that is strange is that the command to log-in to the On-Demand server works when submitted trough Chrome's "Advanced RESTful Client", but fails when submitted from a PHP script.

My guess is that there is something different in the server configuration between Sandbox and On-Demand (SSL??), but have not been able to get any confirmation from AtTask.

Thanks in advance for any insight.

Mark

Comment: Both Those urls look to me like correct login. There is no difference in this between sandbox and on-demand. I am interested in a few things to help you through this. 
1. What is the ticket number you were working with AtTask support. 
2. If its closed please enter a new one with this information and let tier 1 know to contact me Michael Johnson and we can work through in internally. 

Please also provide them the following.
1. The domain you are hitting with your calls.
2. the exact time you attempted to login through the api (This will be so i can pull from server logs)

Answer (score 1):

I have been working with AtTask both as an employee and now a partner for many years.  There are several distinct differences between the preview and productions environments.  These include:

Code Updates: The sandbox can, but not necessary have preview code on it.  This includes prerelease code that will be pushed the production environment in the coming weeks.

Configuration options: This is where we use the preview environment to test and play with new configurations before they hit the production environment.  The recent example of this is the access level upgrade that just happened.  You had the option and were instructed to do this first in the preview environment.

Network Differences: This is overlooked and not widely know.  AtTask uses a content delivery network to make sure the application and fast and responsive worldwide.  The production servers are the only ones that are going through this network. This network allows for faster delivery, but it can sometimes get in the way.  This I believe is what is causing your headache. When the poodle exploit for SSL was released the CDL disabled the affected protocol all together.  This means you need update your client to use the updated protocol.

Comment: I've been suspecting that the issue was related to SSL because the request work in both environments when issued from the Chrome Advanced Rest client, but only work in the sandbox when issued from the script on our server.  The script needs to run from a chron job.  I need to be able to tell our server administrator what the SSL requirements are for AtTask, but I am unable to find that information.  The only difference that I can detect is that On-Demand is using SHA-1 and the Sandbox is using SHA-256.  I've got a feeling that this is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it looks like we are narrowing this down to an SSL issue.  I downloaded the PHP version of the AtTask StreamClient sample, pointed it at the Sandbox server and it ran perfectly. The output was exactly what I expected.

I changed the URL to point to the On-Demand server, and it blew up:

"client created
Logging in...Error: Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to COMPANY.attask-ondemand.com:443 "

Sooo, what is the difference?  How should SSL be set up on my server to allow it to communicate with the AtTask On Demand server?

Thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 0):

I think I've identified the issue. I used Qualys SSL Labs online to to look at the supported protocols and clients for both the Sandbox and the OnDemand servers.  Other than a couple scary things (both sites are succeptible to the poodle exploit), the biggest difference that I found was the client support. SSL Labs test handshake on 34 clients.  The Sandbox passed 32 of the tests.  OnDemand only passed 18 of 34.  The one that really effects me is OpenSSL 1.0.1h, which is the SSL library that is used by my server.

And I don't have any control of how SSL is setup on either server.